# closing a excel workbook after opening in an access vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have this access vba that opens an excel workbook and runs a vba inside of it and then imports data from it.  When i run this code it works and adds the line of new data to the access table.  but I am left with a background task of excel open and have to manually close this through task manager. If i do not close this and try to rerun the program access freezes up.  How to i properly close out of the workbook?

```
Sub runExcelMacros()

    Dim x1 As Excel.Application
    Set x1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    Dim wb As Object, ws As Object
    
    Dim excelFilePath As String
    
    excelFilePath = "filepath"
    
    x1.Visible = False
    
    Set wb = x1.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath)
    
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Controler")
    
    x1.Run "DeleteData"
    
    x1.Run "ImportFile"
    
    x1.Run "FindData"
    
    data1 = ws.Range("B1")
    data2 = ws.Range("B2")
    data3 = ws.Range("B3")
    data4 = ws.Range("B4")
    data5 = ws.Range("B5")
    data6 = ws.Range("B6")
     
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO TargetTable (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6) VALUES ('" & data1 & "', '" & data2 & "', '" & data3 & "', '" & data4 & "', '" & data5 & "', '" & data6 & "')"
        
    x1.Run "DeleteData"

    ' x1.Workbooks.Close

    Set x1 = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "success"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: close Excel: `x1.Quit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close workbook with save or not save then Quit app.

```
   'Tidy up
   xL.DisplayAlerts = False
   wb.Close False
   Set wb = Nothing
   xL.Quit
   Set xL = Nothing
```